# Add a new property to each object of array which will populate dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have paymentList json which is coming from server. I need both date and time. I am using moment.js. I am creating a new property paymentTime and storing time in that property but it is not updating.

```
  this.paymentList.forEach(element => {
                          console.log(moment(element.paymentDate).format("hh:mm A"));
                           console.log(moment(element.paymentDate).format("DD-MMMM-YYYY"));
                           element.paymentTime = moment(element.paymentDate).format("hh:mm A");
                           element.paymentDate = moment(element.paymentDate).format("DD-MMMM-YYYY");
                           console.log(this.paymentList);
                         });


 [
      {
        "paymentDate": "2018-01-09T09:21:13.759Z",
        "loanAmount": "918553377499",
      },
      {
        "paymentDate": "2017-12-27T09:30:41.276Z",
        "loanAmount": "9880712423",

      },
      {
        "paymentDate": "2017-12-27T07:49:09.892Z",
        "loanAmount": "7259945267",

      }

    ]
```

I know if I change my code like this then it will work but I want an elegent way.

```
this.paymentList.forEach(element => {
var array = [];
var obj = {paymentTime: '', paymentDate: '', loanAmount: ''}
obj.paymentDate= moment(element.paymentDate).format("DD-MMMM-YYYY");
obj.paymentTime = moment(element.paymentDate).format("hh:mm A");
obj.loanAmount = element.loanAmount; 
array.push(obj);
this.paymentList = array;

                         });
```

Comment: it seems to be working when i put it into codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpXZpr?editors=0012

Comment: I see, it is working there. strange but sometimes typescript do not let me create property dynamically like the way we create in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your second procedure is good way just modify little bit.

```
    let tempPaymentList:any = [];
    this.paymentList.forEach(element => {
      let obj = {paymentTime: '', paymentDate: '', loanAmount: ''}
      obj.paymentDate= moment(element.paymentDate).format("DD-MMMM-YYYY");
      obj.paymentTime = moment(element.paymentDate).format("hh:mm A");
      obj.loanAmount = element.loanAmount;  
      tempPaymentList.push(obj);
    });
     this.paymentList = tempPaymentList;
     console.log(this.paymentList)
```

Actually its better to take a copy of the main list and then modify the copied list as you wanted.